# Добавить методы в стандартный класс

Tags: android, java, классы

Добрый вечер. 
Мне очень нужно создать несколько методов в классе String. 
Делал через extends (кажется у JSONArray) и создавал новый класс с похожими методами, но с этим путаница и мне это не удобно.

```
String s = new String(); 
s.myNewMethod()
```

Возможно ли вообще такое? Если да, то очень прошу помочь.

Спасибо.

Comment: В Java такое невозможно, в отличие от javascript. А почему нельзя обойтись статическими методами другого класса, принимающими String как аргумент?

Comment: @VladD, было бы удобнее делать что-то типо 
String s = new String();
s.myNewMethod() , чем  myClass.myNewMethod(s). 
Согласитесь ;)

Comment: нет, лучше писать свое. Все знают как работать со String, а если бы там появились новые методы или, еще хуже, переопределились старые...

Comment: @VladD , а как можно открыть стандартный класс? то есть его исходник?)

Comment: @Gorets , данный код только для меня. Другие не имеют доступа к приложению вообще. Так что я хочу сделать удобным для меня.

Comment: класс с модификатором final. И всеравно это глупо, стринг не такой уж и необходимый класс что бы испытывать "не удобства" с ним

Comment: А как это вы смогли сделать extends у String?

Comment: @Чад со стрингом оно не получилось. кажется получалось с JSONArray.

Comment: Вы не сможете заменить

    s = myClass.myNewMethod(s)

на

    String s = new String();
    s.myNewMethod()

(поскольку `String` — неизменяемый.)

Comment: В данном случае обычно делают отдельный класс (типа StringUtils в apache) и добавляют туда свои функции. А строку, у которой должен был бы вызываться новый метод, просто передают параметром.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Класс `String` объявлен как `final`, поэтому вы даже `extends` не сможете на него сделать.

Можно пойти способом агрегации - то есть объявить в своем пакете что-то типа:

```
package ru.emil.sabitov.java.lang;

public class String {
    private java.lang.String m_string;

    public String() {
       m_string=new java.lang.String();
    }

    //например
    public char charAt(int index) {
        return m_string.charAt(index);
    }
    //blah-blah
}
```

далее добавить свой метод в этот мимикрирующий `String` класс точнее в `ru.emil.sabitov.java.lang.String`

Comment: Ага, можно получить много фана, когда новый программист будет смотреть и не понимать, почему java не хочет принимать метод с параметром типа String...

Comment: Пусть смотрит на пакет в котором объявлен класс

Comment: В Objective C, кстати, существующие классы _можно_ расширять. Но доступа к приватным переменным у расширения, разумеется, всё равно не будет.